# cannot find id_ed25519 private and public key file in the ssh file folder

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-server, ssh-keys, openssh

I'm new to ssh and having some trouble with it.

I need to connect my pycharm on my windows10 to the remote server using OpenSSH and the private key in `Tools->deployment->configuration`, but now I can't see id_ed25519 or id_ed25519.pub file in the ssh file folder.

I have generated an Ed25519 key by using the following code:

```
cd ~
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

I can find my private and public key by the following command:

```
cd .ssh
ls
#return: id_ed25519  id_ed25519.pub  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub known_hosts
```

I'm wondering why the private and public key disappeared, or if they were stored somewhere else. But I can find other files returned by the command above.

I even successfully connected to my remote server using the pubkey.

Is there any solution?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Yep! It turned out to be a silly question. I really need to learn more and get familiar.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer!

I generated the key more than once. And every time I needed to copy the key to Windows file system with the following command.

```
cd /mnt/c/users/<my-account>/.ssh/
```

I have two accounts, one for personal utility, the other for work. That was where I made a mistake. I filled the wrong account in the `<my-account>`. That is to say, I logged into the other.

That's really silly.